# API not returning the child property as JSON

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to return an object which is structured as below:

```
public class ApiRouteDocument
{
    //controllername tag
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerDescription { get; set; }
    public IList<RoutePath> Paths;
}
public class RoutePath
{
    //get
    public string Method { get; set; }

    //operationid
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //summary
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //path
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

I am returning in the following way from the controller:

```
[HttpGet("all")]
public IActionResult GetRoute()
{
    var endPoint = _apiExplorer.GetndpointDescription();
    return Json(endPoint);
}
```

But the action returns only the parent properties, the child properties `public IList<RoutePath> Paths;` are never returned to the browser. I did try sending the request from different applications but the child properties are never returned.

The JSON which is returned in the browser:

```
[{"controllerName": "Contact", "controllerDescription": "Contacts"}, {"controllerName": "Transaction", "controllerDescription": null}]
```

Am I missing anything on my startup? do I have to add anything for the JSON return objects?

Comment: `public IList<RoutePath> Paths;` this is a field, not a property. Add `{get;set;}` at the end to it

Comment: that's a very silly mistake of mine